# Removing single and double quotations within a string Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list of sorted characters from a file, however there are quotation marks in the file, and they are messing up the order of my list, so I need to remove them prior to creating my list. I have tried countless approaches, but have been unsuccessful with all of them. Here is the block of code that deals with opening and splitting the file:

```
def openfile(): 
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Select a file.')
    if filename != None:
        thefile = open(filename, 'r')
        contents = thefile.read()
        print(contents)

        translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
        contents = contents.translate(translator)
        contents = contents.replace('"', '').replace("'", '')
        contents = contents.lower()
        wordList = contents.split()
        for word in wordList:
            letter = word.split()
            for letter in word:
                letter.replace('"', '').replace("'", '')

        print('\n', wordList)
        ttk.Button(root, text='Sort', command=splitfile).grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: You don't need to loop through each character and call `replace`. Just call it on the whole string (like what you do above) and remove that inner for loop. Second `replace` returns the new string, so when you do `letter.replace(...` the result is lost. I would suspect that `contents = contents.replace('"', '').replace("'", '')` is enough to get rid of quotes. If that doesn't work, verify that your quotes are regular ASCII quotes.

Comment: Define what "unsuccessful" means. Have you verified that quotes are not getting stripped, or is the final result just not what you want?

Comment: @pushkin i have checked and verified that it is not stripping quotes at all. It will remove all other types of punctuation but for some reason nothing will work to get rid of quotes.

Comment: @pushkin I just checked the file and it does not use regular ASCII quotes which I suspect is the problem.

Comment: I see. And do you want to remove all punctuation or just quotes?

Comment: I want to remove all punctuation, including quotes.

Answer (score 2):

If your file contains fancy unicode quotes, then you'll need to first convert them to regular `'`/`"` quotes.

You can do this using the `unidecode` module:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
contents = unidecode(contents).replace('"', '').replace("'", '')
```

Now if you want to remove *all* punctuation, then you'll need to use a slightly different approach:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
import string
trans_table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
contents = unidecode(contents).translate(trans_table)
```

Comment: It wont let me import unidecode. When i try to run it it returns this error: 
ImportError: No module named 'unidecode'

Comment: Try `pip install`ing it

Comment: Or try easy_install

Answer (score 0):

This should work Semi_final is the list of the words containing the words with punctuation

```
Answer = []

for word in semi_final:
    a = [] 
    for l in word:
        if l != " ' " or l != ' " ': 
           a.append(l)  
    Answer.append("".join(a))
```

Comment: Though it's not immediately clear what `semi_final` is (I take it that's the word?), what this is doing is stripping leading and trailing single quotes off of a word, which is not what OP wants. This won't remove `'` from the word "don't". Also, it will exclude all words that don't have single quotes from the final list.

Comment: Ok. I thought he wants to remove only quotes and not punctuation. . What if this is used: for each character in each word, if it is single quote then remove it.

Comment: Why are there spaces around the quotes? Also, in one of the comments, OP says he wants to remove all the punctuation.

Comment: By mistake. For all punctuation use a number of or operator for all punctuation. All create a list of all punctuation marks and then iterate over it to see if character is a punctuation Mark

Comment: See OP's code. He uses `string.punctuation`, which will get you all punctuation marks. Regardless, the problem is really that the quotes he's trying to remove are not regular quotes, but fancy unicode quotes, so they won't be found in `string.punctuation`. This is why you have to deunicode them first like what I did in my answer.

Comment: Ok. So string.punctuation  would be containing my code that if statement. I was just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Correct. You can use the `in` operator to check if `l` is in `string.punctuation`